# Dynamic attributes (getters/setters) in Swift on data models

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to use `Swift` (which I'm very new at) to create a clean interface for my data models. These models are backed by `Firebase` (though this is ultimately irrelevant to the actual question). What I want to avoid is writing tons of setter/accessor boiler plate code over and over.

For example:

```
class MyData {
  let connection: Firebase!

  private var _name: String? // internal storage, like an iVar in ObjC

  init(connection: Firebase!) {
    self.connection = connection
    self.connection.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
      _name = snapshot["name"]
    }
  }

  var name: {
    get {
      return _name
    }
    set(name) {
      // When the client sets the name, write it to Firebase
      _name = name
      self.connection.childByAppendingPath("name").setValue(name)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure I'm making a lot of mistakes in there. The idea is that the data is first loaded from the server when the instance is instantiated. Subsequently, we could call `my_data_instance.name` to get that name, or `my_data_instance.name = "foo"` and the name would be automatically written to the server.

This requires ~10 lines of code for a single attribute (of which there will be many). Nuts! There must be a better way!

---

EDIT: to be clear, I want to obviate the need to write as MUCH boiler plate code as possible. Consider a library like `Mantle`, where merely defining a `@property` is sufficient to do everything you want. In my opinion, anything more than one single line of code to say `I have an attribute called "name", handle it via Firebase` is overly verbose.

Comment: You could use the Objective-C runtime's metaprogramming capabilities to mass-add properties on-the-fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Key-Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to monitor changes in your properties. More info in [Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID6).

```
import Foundation

private var KVOContext = 0

// Your class must inherit from NSObject
class MyData : NSObject {
    private let propertiesToObserve = ["name", "location"]

    dynamic var name: String
    dynamic var location: String

    init(name: String, location: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        super.init()

        // Add the properties that you want to observe
        for property in self.propertiesToObserve {
            self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: property, options: [.New, .Old], context: &KVOContext)
        }
    }

    // This method is called whenever an observed property is changed
    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if let property = keyPath,
            newValue = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey],
            oldValue = change![NSKeyValueChangeOldKey] {
                print("\(property) changed from \(oldValue) to \(newValue)")
                // If oldValue != newValue, write back to Firebase
        }
    }

    // Remove self as observer of self
    deinit {
        for property in self.propertiesToObserve {
            self.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: property)
        }
    }
}

let data = MyData(name: "John", location: "Chicago")
data.name = "David"         // print: name changed from John to David
data.location = "New York"  // print: location changed from Chicago to New York
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift provides that functionality called *property observer*

```
var name: String {
   didSet {
     self.connection.childByAppendingPath("name").setValue(name)
   }
}
```

There is a second observer `willSet` which is called **before** the value is changed.

Note (from the documentation):

> When you assign a default value to a stored property, or set its
>   initial value within an initializer, the value of that property is set
>   directly, without calling any property observers.

Comment: Sure, but that's still a huge amount of code for each attribute. We only reduced it by a couple of lines.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's the shortest solution in Swift.

Comment: In my example, I used the iVar because I didn't want the setter to write back to firebase. That is, when the `load` completes, wouldn't your code end up calling `didSet` and thus creating a write for every read?

Comment: `didSet` is not called in an `init` method, I updated the answer with a quote from the documentation

Comment: I might need to load data from the server at any point in time, not just in the `init`, in order to sync.

Comment: `didSet` is called **every time** the value of the property is changed except when the property is initialized.